# How many combinations of $n$ balls of up to $n$ different colors are there?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

How many ways can I select a set of $n$ colored balls if I have $n$ different colors to choose from and order does not matter? They can all be the same color or all different. I have no limit on the number of balls of any color.

For example, if I have $3$ colors, then there are $10$ possibilities:
$$\{aaa,
    aab,
    aac,
    abb,
    abc,
    bbb,
    bbc,
    bcc,
    cca,
    ccc\}$$

The pattern seems to match [OEIS A133148](https://oeis.org/A133148) for the first few values of $n$, but I'm not sure why.

---

**Edit:** I believe the binomial $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$ proposed is the correct answer. I realized I was double counting some of the elements when I went to write out everthing.

Comment: See [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: So, you're asking for the sequence of the number of solutions to $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_n=n$ where $x_i\geq 0$.  This is $\binom{2n-1}{n-1}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As proposed by the question you can consider the question to be asking for the non negative integral solutions of the equation $$x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_n=n$$

As already proposed by @Michael Burr in his comment

By star and bars method the answer reveals to be $$\binom  {2n-1}{n-1}$$